# scala-library.jar version in sbt published artifacts

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-0.12

As Scala 2.10.1 is coming out soon, I believe, I want to make sure that artifacts I publish now will automatically work with a scala-library.jar of that version. I use sbt 0.12.2 to publish, and with a setting of

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.0"
```

I get correctly attached the binary compatible version to *my artifact*, e.g.

```
<artifactId>mylibrary_2.10</artifactId>
```

...but the scala library dependency still says 2.10.0:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version> <!-- !!! -->
    </dependency>
```

I suppose that is not correct, and it should use 2.10 or 2.10.+ here?

---

I also tried to add `scalaBinaryVersion := "2.10"` but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Another idea I had was to use `scalaVersion := "2.10.+"`. Sbt takes forever with `Getting Scala 2.10.+ ...`, but it finally goes on fine and the `pom` has this version now for scala-library.jar. So maybe this is the correct way?

Comment: Apparently it's more common to 'cross-build'. See http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Cross-Build for more information. I can not tell you if the solution you found is the correct way.

Comment: Well, one thing I can say now is that `2.10.+` adds serious problems. I just found myself with typer errors in random places, until I found out that somehow some project had already drawn a scala-compiler.jar `2.10.1-RC1`, which apparently is _not binary compatible_.

Comment: Well, the version of the Scala library is equal to the version of Scala you're targeting, since scala-library for version 2.10.1 is different from scala-library 2.10.0. All Scala 2.10 versions are supposed to be binary compatible. Can you post what kind of errors you had when you switched from 2.10.0 to 2.10.1 ?

Comment: They were typical binary problem errors, like methods not found or access error. This was only because some RC version pulled in, I think from scala-actors or so, I don't recall. Now that 2.10.1 is out, I can observe how mixing 2.10.0 and 2.10.1 behaves. Basically it's "ok", but I get a bunch of annoying warning messages from sbt that different artefacts use different scala-lang versions (2.10.0 versus 2.10.1). I'm just ignoring them now, and it seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should be good to go for 2.10.x, since it is meant to be binary compatible between minor versions (as documented in the [release notes](http://www.scala-lang.org/2.10.1)).

In general, you can generate artifacts for arbitrary versions of Scala using the `crossScalaVersions` setting in sbt.

*build.sbt*

```
name := "so-14803362"

scalaVersion := "2.10.0"

crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.0", "2.10.1", "2.10.2")
```

With the above configuration, you can prepend a `+` to sbt commands to run them for each Scala version:

```
> + publish
```

This will build and publish your project's artifacts with each Scala version listed in `crossScalaVersions`.

See the [sbt docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Cross-Build.html#cross-building-a-project) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. I know about cross versions, however, and I happily abandoned that with 2.10. I think it's horrible to increase the amount of artifacts in the world by a factor of three or four, when it's not necessary.

Comment: Good point.  Apparently with 2.10, cross versions yields only a single 2.10.x artifact, but you can still feel confident that you're covered for the listed versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are generating 'fat JAR' everything is determined by the versions of direct dependencies (correct me if I'm wrong) because their direct dependencies are specified too and so forth. Of course this does not guarantee you from some components that depend on Scala library version other than you'd like, you are not guaranteed from components that depends on different versions of some lib and of course Scala is in active development phase but if you stick with some Scala library version and tested well, until this changes you are OK.

But you cannot guarantee everything will be good on next Scala library because you also have other components that probably are not synchronized the same day, right? And, yes, version of Scala library should match version of Scala compiler used.